# How to delete file using lwc/aura from salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Files">
        <template for:each={fileList} for:item="file">
            <div key={file.value} class="slds-box">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-medium-size_8-of-12 slds-size_12-of-12">
                        <p>{file.label}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-medium-size_8-of-12 slds-size_12-of-12">
                        <p>{file.value}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-medium-size_4-of-12 slds-size_12-of-12">
                        <lightning-button label="Delete" variant="brand" data-id={file.value} onclick={deleteSelectedRecords}></lightning-button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS file

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api,track } from "lwc";
import getRelatedFilesByRecordId from "@salesforce/apex/DeleteFileController.getRelatedFilesByRecordId";
import deleteSelectedfile from "@salesforce/apex/DeleteFileController.deleteSelectedfile";
import { deleteRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class FileList extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId
    
    @track fileList =[]
    recordIds;
    @wire(getRelatedFilesByRecordId, {recordId: '$recordId'})

    wiredResult({data, error}){
      if(data)
      {
        console.log(data)
        this.fileList = Object.keys(data).map(item=>({"label":data[item],"value": item}))
        console.log(this.fileList)
      }
      if(error)
      {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    
    deleteSelectedRecords(event)
    {
      console.log('id of button:' , event.currentTarget.dataset.id)
      let recordIds = event.currentTarget.dataset.id
      console.log('recordId set: ',recordIds)

      
      deleteSelectedfile({recordIds})
      .then(result => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Selected record is deleted!',
            variant: 'success',
          }),
        );
        return refreshApex(this.fileList);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.message = undefined;
        this.error = error;
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error creating records',
            message: error.body.pageError[0].message,
            variant: 'error',
          
          }),
        );
        console.log("error", JSON.stringify(this.error));
      });
      
}
```

apex class

```
public with sharing class DeleteFileController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<Id, String> getRelatedFilesByRecordId(String recordId) {
        List<ContentDocumentLink> files = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId];
        List<ID> fileIDs = new List<ID>();
        for (ContentDocumentLink docLink : files)
        {
            fileIDs.add(docLink.ContentDocumentId);
        }
         
        List<ContentVersion> docs = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, FileExtension, Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: fileIDs];
        Map<ID, String> mapIdTitle = new Map<ID, String>();
        for(ContentVersion docLink : docs)
        {
            mapIdTitle.put(docLink.ContentDocumentId, docLink.Title);
        }
        return mapIdTitle;
    }
@AuraEnabled
    public static Id deleteSelectedfile(Id docIds){
        try{
            System.debug('inside apex class');
            delete [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id=:docIds];
            return 'SUCCESS';
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: are you facing some error?

Comment: i am able to fetch file and also in deleteSelectedRecords(event) i am getting file id in recordIds but it is not going inside apex class method and not performing dml operation. can anyone help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the definition of your method
public static Id deleteSelectedfile(Id docIds) to
public static String deleteSelectedfile(Id docIds) beacuse you are  returning String not Id which cause it to go in catch which result in transaction rollback.

Comment: when i change from ID to string it is showing me as 'Success' msg but it is not getting inside apex class and not deleting file.

Comment: I tried the same thing and its working for me. See if you are passing correct docId or not. And hope you are changing return type to String not the argument type.

Comment: no its still not working

Comment: In that case probably you are making some small mistake. If you want we can connect to fix this.

Comment: hey its working fine thanks for help